# Jazz and hip hop aren't genres but approaches to music?

Tags: genre, jazz, hip-hop

I remember a friend of mine (who studied music) told me once:

> Jazz and hip hop are not really genres. But they are actually
>   approaches to music.

Have any famous jazz or hip hop artists held this viewpoint? May I have the resource to the interview, recording or writing where they have expressed this view, along with their reasons?

Comment: Google searching didn't seem to give any relevant result: 
https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&sxsrf=ALeKk01zM1i4gYJTMSqCuLYdmB0rv120uQ%3A1589470715749&ei=-2W9XreiLZvVz7sPqaae-Ag&q=jazz+and+hip+hop+an+approach+to+music+&oq=jazz+and+hip+hop+an+approach+to+music+&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzoECAAQR1DBkAZYwZAGYN6SBmgCcAB4AIABgAGIAYABkgEDMC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj3i5Lr17PpAhWb6nMBHSmTB48Q4dUDCAw&uact=5\
. Maybe I could change "elaborate" to "justify"?

Comment: The premise of the original statement is wrong. The fact that Hip-Hop might be both a culture and an approach to music doesn't in any way stop it from also being a genre. I don't know of any famous musician who has made a similar claim about Jazz.

Answer (score 2):

A common answer you'll get is that hip-hop is a culture with 4 pillars: breakdancing, graffiti, MCing, and DJing. The musical side of things is only one part of the entire culture. Afrika Bambaataa, an influencial early hip-hop artist has spoken about hip-hop as a cultural movement and mental approach instead of a particular musical genre: https://news.cornell.edu/stories/2012/11/afrika-bambaataa-raps-early-hip-hop-history